# Generate random number based on time

Tags: java, random

I tried to generate a random number with this code based on time :

```
  public class RandomInt {
     private Random generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
     double randomGenerator(){
         return generator.nextDouble()*0.5;

     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new RandomInt();
     }
 }
```

But when I run the java class, it shows nothing. Help me with this please. Thank you

PS : I'm newbie

Comment: It doesn't print anything because you didn't tell it to print anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
System.out.println(new RandomInt().randomGenerator());
```

Simply calling `new RandomInt()` will instantiate the object for you.  Your method `randomGenerator()` actually generates the random number and `System.out.println()` prints whatever you tell it to the console.

To get a solid integer number you will need to use a different method on the Random class. [`nextInteger()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) should be what you're looking for.

Comment: It shows 0.4949360775739011 Is there any way to get solid integer number?

Comment: It shows 316473234. Any way to get just 4 or 5 digits?

Comment: Well I advise you to explore more and go through a nice book on java, else no doubt you would have endless questions. Perhaps people do not like my answer :(